# Detecting duplicate resources in a single maven project

Tags: maven, duplicates

The [maven duplicate finder plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin) looks like a great way to detect when the same resource exists in more than one module.  What I need is something much simpler: detection of the same resource in the *same* module.

(**Update:** filed [an issue](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin/issues/16) against the maven duplicate finder plugin to see if it's expected to detect this situation or not.)

Here is a demonstration of the maven duplicate finder plugin failing to detect the sort of situation that I'm concerned with:

```
$ cat pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stackoverflow.mattmchenry</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvn-dups</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources_es</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>

$ find src/ -type f
src/main/resources/Strings_es.properties
src/main/resources/Strings.properties
src/main/resources_es/Strings_es.properties    

$ mvn com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.2:check[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.stackoverflow.mattmchenry:mvn-dups:jar:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.2:check]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [duplicate-finder:check {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Checking compile classpath
[INFO] Checking runtime classpath
[INFO] Checking test classpath
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 22 22:44:40 EST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: No idea about this plugin but you could achieve this with in 'simple' single line of bash: `find . | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "^ *1 "`. HIH

Comment: @ZNK-M: nice -- I didn't know about that `rev` command.  But I'm hoping for something that works as part of Maven.

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate-finder plugin can not help you in this specific situation.

The problem is that it works on the classpath, not on the source folders. Which, in the maven case, consists of the local folders in target and the artifacts. If you have multiple resource source folders (in your case `src/main/resources` and `src/main/resources_es`), these files will be copied into `target/classes` by maven before the plugin actually runs and so it can not detect this situation.

The duplicate-finder plugin can only help

- if the multiple resource folders end up in separate artifacts (jars)
- if one of the resources is for the compile folder (target/classes) and one is for tests (target/test-classes)

The duplicate-finder plugin never looks at the source folders, only at the classpath folders.

(I am one of the main authors of the plugin.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the maven-duplicate finder plugin which exactly does the job you need? One other solution is to use [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html), but it looks like you need to implement your [own enforcer-rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html). I would prefer to use maven-duplicate-finder-plugin.

Comment: I've edited my question to demonstrate that the duplicate finder plugin does not detect the situation that I'm worried about.

Comment: That means to create an issue on the github and hoping that it will be fixed otherwise just fork the plugin and create and fix it your own...

Comment: Okay, submitted https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin/issues/16.  If they agree it's a bug, I'll give you the check mark.  :)